# Cannot find module express: docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, mongoose

```
FROM node:18.16.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I have this Dockerfile, when I run docker-compose up I get this error :
Error: Cannot find module 'express'

I tried updating the docker file but it did not work

Comment: Check if you have package.json file with `express` included in your `dependencies` json.

Comment: My package.json file looks like this, express is already added "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.1.1"
  }

Comment: How do you run your container? My guess is that you map your source directory to `/usr/src/app`.

Comment: I have that mapping already in my Dockerfile. I have a docker-compose.yml file and i run docker-compose up

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out by Sachin, we need to add express dependency in package.json file.

Better solution:

```
"dependencies": {
    "dependency1": "^v-xxx",
    "dependency2": "^v-xxx",
    "express": "^4.17.1"  (version-4.17 is just an example)
  }
```

Not recommended way: (Alter these in Dockerfile)

```
RUN npm install
RUN npm install express
```

Being said that you need to alter your Dockerfile in a way that it will not exit once the server is started. Hope this helps.

Comment: My package .json file looks like this: "dependencies" {
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mongoose": "^7.1.1"
  }

Comment: almost there just one syntax issue:
"dependencies" { "ejs": "^3.1.9", "express": "^4.18.2", "mongoose": "^7.1.1" }

should be- "dependencies" : { "ejs": "^3.1.9", "express": "^4.18.2", "mongoose": "^7.1.1" }  (the missing colon)

Comment: Pasting log of docker build for you: Step 6/6 : CMD ["npm", "start"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c31fb068f80b
Successfully built c31fb068f80b
Successfully tagged npmtest:latest

Comment: I have checked i have the colon there and I have update the package.json file, this is my updated Dokerfile 

FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm install express

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]

Comment: I run this command docker-compose up and get this error: Cannot find module express

Comment: Just not right. what we are seeing here is a Dockerfile. you need to build an image and then run it. docker build -t yourimagename .  and then docker run yourimagename -d. docker-compose works on different model which requires docker-compose.yml file. I leave that exercise to you.

Comment: I have a docker-compose.yml file below:

version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: docker-node-mongoo
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    external_links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'